# Could you share a link to a good intro into Java FX 2.0?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I didn't hurry to learn JavaFX as its first generation emerged but believe JavaFX 2.0 has strong chance becoming a very important technology revolutionizing (and strengthening a lot) JVM languages' client presentation. So I'd like to begin studying it right now, with Java FX 2.0 Beta (as far as I understand studying JavaFX 1.x is pretty senseless in my case as Java FX 2.0 is very much different).

So as Google doesn't help much at this moment I'd like to ask if you suggest any links to study.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start with this:

http://download.oracle.com/javafx/index.html

Comment: Thanks! Looks ridiculous but I haven't seen this page (despite the fact I've already downloaded JavaFX 2.0 SDK from Oracle). Strangely Google show this link only on the third page of the results for the "javafx 2.0" query, it should really be among the first ones...

Comment: Yeah I know, that happened to me also, so I book marked it. Probably the more links there are the higher it will appear.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who are as well interested in the question here is what of interesting have I found myself.

http://fxexperience.com/2011/07/introducing-fxml/
and some more links here:
http://jonathangiles.net/blog/?p=1093